# The cheapest online service to store 3TB of archive data?

Tags: backup, cloud-service, cloud-storage, dropbox

Now I'm using Dropbox with 1TB plan which costs me 100$/year.

But I need 3TB and without any smart synchronization and stuff - so I can just upload my archives and download them back when I need.

It's very important that I actually can **delete** the files (which I uploaded) from my HDD and they should still be available for download. So this should not be like synchronization but just a storage.

It should also have a good upload speed, at least 16mbps (I have 100mbps connection from Ukraine).

Are there any good services/cloud platforms where I can keep my archives cheaper than for $300/year?

Comment: Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not services – so this seems off-topic. For details, you might refer to our Meta post on [Are hosting recommendation requests on-topic?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/675/185)

Comment: @Izzy ok, where should I ask it? This seems to be offtopic too: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/155/online-storage-service-with-15gb-that-works-well-on-linux?rq=1  And this: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/18235/other-services-like-bitcasa?rq=1

Comment: @Izzy see http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/44/are-web-service-recommendations-off-topic?rq=1

Comment: Vlad, what you're asking for is expressively *hosting* – read the post you've linked thoroughly for the definition of "web service". You're looking for "web storage", i.e. a place to store your files, which is not software.